# How to import and substitute environment variables of other gradle libraries as they are

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, gradle

I am currently uploading a library through jitpack.

AutoConfiguration is in progress in the library as follows

```
@AutoConfiguration
public class MongoAutoConfig {
}
```

Also, the library has the following environment variable values.

- application-yml

```
de:
  flapdoodle:
    mongodb:
      embedded:
        version: 6.0.6
```

I want to make this value the same as the environment variable in other projects that depend on the library
What should I do?